# How to localize JavaFX FileChooser dialog?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is there an option to localize JavaFX FileChooser dialog?
In Swing JFileChooser localization was pretty simple (over `UIManager`).
But i can't find similar functionality in JavaFX.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/ricemery/FileChooserFx) might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can. From the [`FileChooser` Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html):

> Provides support for standard platform file dialogs. These dialogs
>   have look and feel of the platform UI components which is independent
>   of JavaFX.

Since these are native File Chooser dialogs, the text displayed in them will be controlled by the locale of the platform (i.e. the regional settings chosen on the user's machine at the OS level). Note that this is probably what you want anyway, as the user likely has these set the way they want. You could experiment with changing your regional settings and seeing if it changes the file chooser.

Comment: Yes, `filechooser` uses platform regional settings, but my app allows user to switch language "on the fly" and only `filechooser` still shows "unlocalized" text. But, umm, maybe idea of "on the fly" translation is not so good... Anyway i accept the answer...