# How to change fileChooser Open Dialog Buttons' Text in javaFX and make the original window from where it's launched inaccessible?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, filechooser

I want to use javaFX FileChooser class because i need the openDialog. The problem is that i want to change the Text of the Buttons "Open" and "Cancel" than make the Stage from where the openDialog is launched inaccessible. 
i'm using this code to open the FileChooser :

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
Window stage = null;
fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("OWL (*.owl)", "*.owl"));
fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
```

I get the following window : [image]
So my questions are :

> **1- Is it possible to change the Text of the buttons in the red rectangle from "Open" to "Ouvrir" and "Cancel" to "Annuler" ? if Yes, How ?** 
>   **2- How to do so that the Stage from where it's launched inaccessible (not clickable) when it's opened until you click on "Cancel" or "Open"?**

Comment: I doubt you can localize the FileChooser, because it is a native Dialog. That means the text displayed in the FileChooser is controlled by the locale of the platform on which it is running as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865869/how-to-localize-javafx-filechooser-dialog). I am not sure about the Modality Behavior, but on Windows Systems I think the FileChooser is already modal, so clicks to the stage will be intercepted.